# How to enable and disable radiobutton inside Radiogroup items in dialog

Tags: android

i have alert dialog, which consist of radio-group, my question is how to enable &disable radio button, when i click on one radio button, it should disable till, click on next radio button. please help me out.

```
public class AddDriverStateDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private static AddDriverStateDialog addDriverStateDialog;

    // Data references
    private int DRIVER_STATE = 0;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private int year, month, day, hours, minutes;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");
    private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");


    // UI References
    private View view;
    public LinearLayout editableDetails;
    private RadioRealButtonGroup radioButtonGroup;
    private  RadioRealButton radioButton_offduty,radioButton_onduty,radioButton_sleeper,radioButton_driving,radioButton_yard,radioButton_personal;
    private EditText note, et_date, time, odoReading, location;
    private CheckBox insertLog, switchDriver;
    private Spinner spinner;

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    // Picker Dialogs
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    private TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    public static AddDriverStateDialog newInstance(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        if (addDriverStateDialog == null) {
            addDriverStateDialog = new AddDriverStateDialog();
        }
        addDriverStateDialog.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        return addDriverStateDialog;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Initialise UI elements
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity).inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_driver_state, null);
        editableDetails = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_addDriverState_editableDetails);
        radioButtonGroup = (RadioRealButtonGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_dialog_addDriverState_driverStates);
        note = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_addDriverState_note);
        et_date = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_addDriverState_date);
        time = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_addDriverState_time);
        odoReading = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_addDriverState_odometer);
        location = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_addDriverState_location);
        insertLog = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkBox_addDriverStare_insertLog);
        switchDriver = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkBox_addDriverStare_switchDriver);
        radioButton_offduty = (RadioRealButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_offDuty);
        radioButton_onduty=(RadioRealButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_onDuty);
        radioButton_sleeper=(RadioRealButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_sleeperBerth);
        radioButton_driving=(RadioRealButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_driving);
        radioButton_yard=(RadioRealButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_yard_move);
        radioButton_personal=(RadioRealButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_personal_conveyance);
        // Initialise Data references
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Get current dateTime and time
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
        hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


        // Initialise data references
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mainActivity, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                et_date.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }
        }, year, month, day);

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(mainActivity, 0, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                time.setText(timeFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }
        }, hours, minutes, false);


        // UI Interaction listeners
        /* Driver State Selection Listener */
        radioButtonGroup.setOnClickedButtonListener(new RadioRealButtonGroup.OnClickedButtonListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickedButton(RadioRealButton button, int position) {
                switch (button.getId()) {
                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_offDuty:

                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_OFFLINE;
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_onDuty:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_ONLINE;
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_sleeperBerth:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_SLEEPER;
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_driving:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_DRIVING;
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_yard_move:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_YARD_MOVE;
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_personal_conveyance:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_PERSONAL_CONVEYANCE;
                        break;
                }

            }

        });

        et_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        insertLog.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    editableDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    editableDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        switchDriver.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    radioButton_onduty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    radioButton_driving.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    radioButton_yard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    radioButton_personal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    radioButtonGroup.setOnClickedButtonListener(new RadioRealButtonGroup.OnClickedButtonListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClickedButton(RadioRealButton button, int position) {
                            switch (button.getId()) {
                                case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_offDuty:
                                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_OFFLINE;
                                    break;


                                case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_sleeperBerth:
                                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_SLEEPER;
                                    break;

                            }
                        }

                    });
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity)
                .setTitle("Update Driver Log")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mainActivity.updateDashboard(DRIVER_STATE, note.getText().toString());
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want for exemple click in radioButton_offduty and desable all others?

Comment: i want radioButton_offduty should be disabled, till i select another button

Answer (score 0):

So to do what you whant do this:

```
radioButtonGroup.setOnClickedButtonListener(new RadioRealButtonGroup.OnClickedButtonListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickedButton(RadioRealButton button, int position) {
                switch (button.getId()) {
                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_offDuty:

                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_OFFLINE;
                        radioButton_offduty.setEnabled(false);
                        radioButton_onduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_sleeper.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_driving.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_yard.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_personal.setEnabled(true);
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_onDuty:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_ONLINE;
                        radioButton_offduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_onduty.setEnabled(false);
                        radioButton_sleeper.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_driving.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_yard.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_personal.setEnabled(true);
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_sleeperBerth:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_SLEEPER;
                        radioButton_offduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_onduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_sleeper.setEnabled(false);
                        radioButton_driving.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_yard.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_personal.setEnabled(true);
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_driving:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_DRIVING;
                        radioButton_offduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_onduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_sleeper.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_driving.setEnabled(false);
                        radioButton_yard.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_personal.setEnabled(true);
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_yard_move:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_YARD_MOVE;
                        radioButton_offduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_onduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_sleeper.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_driving.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_yard.setEnabled(false);
                        radioButton_personal.setEnabled(true);
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_personal_conveyance:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverLog.STATE_PERSONAL_CONVEYANCE;
                        radioButton_offduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_onduty.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_sleeper.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_driving.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_yard.setEnabled(true);
                        radioButton_personal.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                }

            }

        });
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as9Zu.png)

Comment: I see the adapter now

Comment: you whant to disable inside this method **switchDriver.setOnCheckedChangeListener()**, I dont know where you want to disable the button can you tell me? I assumed that you want in **onclickListener**.

Comment: @shashidhar can you add images of dialog to see?

Comment: i have  uploaded

Comment: and add an image with one button clicked to see what happens thanks